# Saving document to a particular folder on a different server

Tags: java, jboss

I have 2 applications on different servers (Server A and Server B) and would like to save the documents to folder on server A. on server A i can just save it to folder E:\XXX\XXX folder. but using application on Server what would be the folder structure \ipaddress\XXX\XXXX this did not work, can any one help me on that. We are using Java application on Jboss AS

Comment: What do you mean, it didn't work?  Did you get a permission denied error?  Do you have server A set up to share `E:\XXX` as `\\ipaddress\XXX`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, just Map the folder on Server A as a drive, lets say S: in the explorer.

To do so, just open up an explorer and go to My Computer. If you are using Windows 7 (or Server 2008), then there is a button that says "Map Network Drive". Select the drive letter you want to assign to it, in our case S and then enter the path "\'Server-IP-here'\'folder-to-share'\".

On Windows XP, you can do the same thing when you go to the "Tools" menu on My Computer.

Make sure that the folder you want to share is available on the network/you shared it.

Now you can access the folder from your Java Application with S:\

Comment: we are using windows 2003 server is there any way i can access the folder directly I gave enough permission for user running the appliction